# Can I stop applications from grabbing focus in OS X?

Tags: macos, user-interface, settings

Applications stealing focus is on of my biggest UI pet peeves.  There's rarely a good reason for an application that I'm not using to interrupt what I'm doing.

Is there a way to disable focus-grabbing globally in OS X?

Comment: You may find better luck on http://superuser.com/

Comment: The programing relatedness and SuperUser appropriateness of this depend on whether he want a tool to "fix" this on his own machine, or wants a programmatic method to do it to his users...

Comment: Its probably a more appropriate question for superuser.

Answer (score -3):

The only time I've ever seen "focus stealing" was when I was launching a bunch of applications at once, but didn't want them to gain focus. I do this when I start work in the morning; I have a script that launches about 5 or 6 apps I always use.

If this is your specific case, the behavior can be suppressed in apple script.